# Excel function query using a range and 2 columns - very stuck

Tags: excel, function, range, excel-2010

Using the example below, I want a formula that, for any given `Work ID` will count through the  list and return the number of results per `Category` value. (Unfortunately, I really need to do this in Excel if I can.)

For example, where Work ID = C and Category = P3, I would expect the result to be 5. For Work Item A / Category P1 the result would be 0.

I can establish TRUE / FALSE for a single row using (for the first example): `IF(A9="C",B9="P3"),1,0)` (this returns 1 of course) but I don't know how to write it for a range.

```
Work ID Category
A         P3
A         P4
A         P4
A         P4
A         P4
B         P4
C         P5
C         P3
C         P4
C         P3  
C         P3
C         P3
C         P3
```

Many thanks in advance to anyone who can crack this for me - you're a life saver :o)

Comment: `COUNTIFS` or a pivot table will work. A pivot table would be best.

Comment: Cheers Doug, yes I had pretty much got there with a pivot table but (unless i'm unaware, being new to pivot tables) it only returns values currently in the columns? e.g. soon enough, my data will feature several other Work IDs (I know what their values will be) and there will be P1 and P2 Category values coming through. So I figured that using functions, I can put these in a table now (with zero counts), whereas the pivot table would only show them once they have a value?

Comment: That's one of the beauties of pivot tables they grow with, and account for, new data automatically. Especially if your data is contained in a Table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `COUNTIFS` function:

```
=COUNTIFS(A2:A14;"=C";B2:B14;"=P3")
```

or

```
=COUNTIFS(A2:A14;"=A";B2:B14;"=P1")
```